# VisualStudio 2019 proporties->Settings.Settings Как вывести в виде таблицы? сейчас открывается ввиде xml документа

Tags: visual-studio-2019

подскажите пожалуйста!
VisualStudio 2019 ,
окошко "Обозреватель решений",
Выбираю proporties -  Settings.Settings,
вместо таблицы открывается файл xml,
как сделать чтобы отображалась таблица?

[image: вид текущего окошка VisualStudio2019 и как надо]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Правый клик на файле
- Выбрать "Открыть с помощью"
- Выбрать "Settings Designer" из списка одиночным кликом.
- Нажать "Установить по умолчанию" справа.